# como puedo agregar un mensaje de confirmacion?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy desarrollando un login pero quiero agregarle mensajes a la app por ejemplo que cuando un usuario se registre le muestre un mensaje de que se ha registrado correctamente, he intentado mediante un viewbag pero no me funciono el mensaje, alguna sugerencia? he estado investigando pero no he logrado encontrar algun caso similar. Agradezco cualquier ayuda soy nuevo en esto y no tengo mucho conocimiento del tema. gracias

controlador:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Usuario u, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string clave = u.Password;
            string encrip = Encriptar.Hash(clave);
            var user = db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Correo == u.Correo && x.Password == encrip).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u.Correo, false);
                Session["uname"] = (u.Nombre + u.Apellido1).ToString();
                if (ReturnUrl != null)
                {
                    return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                }
                return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
            }
        }
        return View();

    }
```

vista:

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <div class="input-group mb-3 form-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Correo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Digite su correo" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Correo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group mb-3 form-group">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Digite su contraseña" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4 ">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger">login</button>

                 
            }
```

Comment: cuando el usuario se registra se refresca la página?

Comment: cuando el usuario se registra lo lleva a la pagina de inicio, talvez se podria cambiar el rediccionamiento a la misma pagina y agregar el mensaje ahi

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando `TempData` antes de redirigir a tu vista. en este temporal
almacenas el mensaje.

Ejemplo:

```
if (ReturnUrl != null)
                {
                    TempData["msg"] = "Operación correcta";
                    return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                }
                return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
```

En tu vista agregas al inicio

```
@{
    TempData.Keep("msg");
}
```

y el acceso

```
TempData["msg"].ToString()
```